# searchView in toolbar has a paddingBottom when fitsSystemWindows

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

In my style.xml:

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

In my toolbar.xml:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
```

And when I input something it looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsFOC.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9XaZ.jpg)

So my question is: 
Why it has a bottom padding? And, how to use fitsSystemWindows but make the bottom padding zero?

My temporary solution is:
use android:paddingTop="XXdp" instead of  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

but it not elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just search on Baidu and found a perfect solution.

http://www.th7.cn/Program/Android/201603/780326.shtml

just add this to manifast

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: It cost me a lot of time searching in google and finally get an answer in Chinese website.WTF